# Ruby on Rails .last throwing undefined methor error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using a standard .each loop to list the names of authors assigned to a contract for a particular project.

This works fine, when there's just one author:

```
<% @product.contracts.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.author.full_name %>
<% end %>
```

But more than one author and it looks really ugly. So I tried this:

```
<% @product.contracts.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.author.full_name %>
  <%= "," unless p == @product.last %>
<% end %>
```

But that didn't work. I got: `undefined method last for #<Product:0x105e7ac38>`

Then, I tried this: `<%= @product.map{|p| p.author.full_name}.join(",") %>`

That didn't work either. I got: `undefined method map for #<Product:0x105c6d760>`

I'm sure I'm doing something silly wrong, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call these methods on a singular object, rather than an array of them(which support `last` and `map`).

`@product` is a model object rather than an array of them, which is what you are expecting.

From your code, you want:

```
@product.contracts.last
```

or

```
 @product.contracts.map{|contract| contract.author.full_name}.join(",")
```

because contracts(assuming) is an array that responds to `map` and `last`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @product.contracts.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.author.full_name %>
  <% 
     # No point comparing p which is a contract object as it will never match with
     # a product object and as mentioned before, @product is not an array so 
     # .last wont work
  %>
  <%= "," unless p == @product.last %>
<% end %>
```

Possible solution:

```
<% @product.contracts.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.author.full_name %>
  <%= "," unless p == @product.contracts.last %>
<% end %>
```